# How to Override Create Payment method from Prepare Payment page [AP503000] in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm using Acumatica 2022 R1 Build 22.103.0018. I want to be able to define the ExtRefNbr value either after calling the Process event on Prepare Payment (AP503000) or before calling the Process event on Release Payments (AP505200). The main issue is since both of these methods are not PXActions just plain methods, I'm not sure if I can actually override them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the Prepare Payments screen in this way:

```
    public delegate void CreatePaymentsDelegate(List<APAdjust> list, PayBillsFilter filter, CurrencyInfo info, PaymentMethod paymenttype);

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void CreatePayments(List<APAdjust> list, PayBillsFilter filter, CurrencyInfo info, PaymentMethod paymenttype, CreatePaymentsDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        baseMethod(list, filter, info, paymenttype);
        // add your code here   
    }
```

I highly recommend you to review  [T300 Acumatica Customization Platform](https://openuni-test.acumatica.com//pdf/T300_Acumatica_Cust_Platform.pdf) training course.

Comment: That makes sense, but while the new method is called there is an error: PX.Data.PXRedirectRequiredException: 'NextProcessing'

Comment: You can try to override CreatePayment method in APPaymentEntry graph in the same way. This method is called for each document from APPaybills graph when you process the records.

Comment: I tried both in APReleaseChecks as well as in APPaymentEntry. In APReleaseChecks since the ReleasePayments method is not virtual I couldn't override it and in APPaymentEntry, the CreatePayment method only lets me override (for some reason), the overload that receives APInvoice apdoc as parameters, the others while also virtual and public don't get recognized or plainly don't let the process run correctly.